# Hive: No results are displayed from the query

Tags: datetime, hive, hive-query

I am writing a query on this table to get the sum of size for all the directories, group by directory where date is yesterday. I am getting no output from the below query.

```
test.id        test.path           test.size     test.date
1   this/is/the/path1/fil.txt      232.24           2019-06-01
2   this/is/the/path2/test.txt     324.0            2016-06-01
3   this/is/the/path3/index.txt    12.3             2017-05-01
4   this/is/the/path4/test2.txt    134.0            2019-03-23
5   this/is/the/path1/files.json   2.23             2018-07-23
6   this/is/the/path1/code.java    1.34             2014-03-23
7   this/is/the/path2/data.csv     23.42            2016-06-23
8   this/is/the/path3/test.html    1.33             2018-09-23
9   this/is/the/path4/prog.js      6.356            2019-06-23
4   this/is/the/path4/test2.txt    134.0            2019-04-23
```

```
SELECT regexp_replace(path,'[^/]+$',''), sum(cast(size as decimal)) 
from test WHERE date > date_sub(current_date, 1) GROUP BY path,size;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not `group by size`, only by `regexp_replace(path,'[^/]+$','')`.
Also, since you want only yesterday's rows why do you use `WHERE date > '2019%`?
You can get yesterday's date with `date_sub(current_date, 1)`:

```
select 
  regexp_replace(path,'[^/]+$',''), 
  sum(cast(size as decimal)) 
from test 
where date = date_sub(current_date, 1) 
group by regexp_replace(path,'[^/]+$','');
```

Comment: Do you have rows with yesterday's date?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `WHERE date >= '2019-01-01'`. Using `%` in matching strings, for example your `2019%`, only works with LIKE, not inequality matching.

The example you gave looks like you want all rows in calendar year 2019.

For yesterday, you want

```
  WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(current_date, -1)
    AND date < current_date
```

This works even if your `date` column contains timestamps.